# Is it possible to directly link to a google drive folder in preview mode?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google Drive's api to essentially host and link to images from an external site.

The problem I'm encountering, is when people upload a bunch of photos in the provided folder, I seem to only be able to use the webViewLink to view individual photos. I noticed that in the google drive folder, there is a very convenient photo preview that lets you click left and right to browse photos.

I was wondering if this preview view is possible to be linked to directly. It doesn't seem like the url changes but if this is possible, any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your user has permission to view the folder, you can use the embedded folder view to embed a view of the folder, which should show all the images contained within.

The URL pattern looks like `https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id={{folderId}}#grid` where `{{folderId}}` is the ID of the drive folder.

That gives a nice preview, but requires the user has view access on the folder. If they do not, you'll need to auth the request with your own token so that it will render properly for the end user.